# Error: Authentication code missing (Mongoose-encryption)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, body-parser

im getting this error while login a registred user 
ofcourse i got this error after using ***dotenv* package** to secure my database encryption key

but `proccess.env.SECRET` is working currectly

i guess my problem is here :

```
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, {           
    secret: process.env.SECRET,         
    encryptedFields: ["password"],     
});
```

***app.js :***

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const encrypt = require("mongoose-encryption");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
});

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
});

                                         //_
//     encrypting password field         // | 
userSchema.plugin(encrypt, {             // | i guess problem is here
    secret: process.env.SECRET,          // |
    encryptedFields: ["password"],       //_|
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

***error :***

```
Error: Authentication code missing
    at Object.schema.methods.authenticateSync (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\mongoose-encryption\lib\plugins\mongoose-encryption.js:419:23)
    at model.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\mongoose-encryption\lib\plugins\mongoose-encryption.js:239:47)
    at Kareem.execPreSync (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\kareem\index.js:115:16)
    at model.syncWrapper [as $__init] (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\kareem\index.js:232:12)
    at model.Document.init (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:513:8)
    at completeOne (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2853:12)
    at model.Query.Query._completeOne (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2094:7)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2138:10)
    at Immediate.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Amir\Desktop\security\node_modules\mquery\lib\utils.js:116:16)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:456:21)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

1. Navigate to your database using your terminal using (as much I can see you use mongo) ex:
   `show dbs`, `use databaseName`, `show collections`, `db.databaseName.find()` and then
2. Empty your database `db.databaseName.drop()` (If it is important stuff, then keep it somewhere safe so you can reuse it again, should be easy if you use Postman)
3. And recreate your database

Answer (score 4):

You should delete the existing documents in your database and run the code again with an empty document.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the thing is that you might be using your new encryption on data which was stored before the addition of encryption , whereas if you check the same with the new data it will work fine , thus you should create a new database first so that you add new items in it , and it will hopefully work for you . :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I was facing with the same issue, but it occurs only to the data which you have stored in the database previously using mongoose-encryption without dotenv.
However, it works fine

1. when you create a new data by registering as new user.
2. Drop the database and create a new one. (Make sure you save the data before doing it).
   :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you might changed the "encryption key". If you can find out the one you made it at start, then you can still check and use this database in your (.js) file. However, "Error: Authentication code missing (Mongoose-encryption)" does not mean you destroy it. You still can use.  Have a try!

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
You should try to Drop your Database once and Start the server agein.

It may be possible that you have changed your encryption "secret" code a bit while transferring it to the .env file.

Don't forget to take backup before dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this error, drop the collection you are trying to encrypt (with `db.<collection-name>.drop()` and create it again.

You are seeing this error because some of the data in your database is not encrypted while the rest of it is encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was triggered by the usage of `findOneAndReplace`.
I wanted to replace the record if it already existed in this way:

```
const newCredentials = { userId, securedCredentials};
await Credentials.findOneAndReplace({ userId }, newCredentials, {upsert:true});
```

I noticed that the code works if we try to add the object in the standard way:

```
await new Credentials(newCredentials).save();
```

Thus the problem is that we are trying to upsert a non-encrypted object. Ok, let's encrypt it then! I tried by calling the `encrypt` method, but that doesn't work

```
// The following line doesn't work. `encrypted` is undefined
const encrypted = await new Credentials(newCredentials).encrypt(); 

// This does work though...
const credentials = new Credentials(newCredentials);
credentials.encrypt((err) => {console.log(credentials)});
```

As I couldn't figure out how to do this in an atomic operation, I just went the long way:

```
await Credentials.deleteOne({userId});
await new Credentials(newCredentials).save();
```

If someone has an idea about how to atomize the operation, it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was using ES6 version as i was using import to import all the modules by converting it to const app = require("ejs") sort of things all worked  well . May be mongoose-encryption is not compatible with ES6 as i have tried doing import {config} from "dotenv" but still did not worked for me.

And do add this at the top of your .js file

Comment: Please [edit] to make more obvious how  this is answering the question at the top of this page, ideally according to [answer]. - Or delete this, if it is not meant to be an answer.

Answer (score -3):

You don't have the MongoDB server port 27017 active on your system.
To do that, simply write "mongod" command in another tab of your hyper terminal.